# How to install pywinauto for 64-bit Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pywinauto

I have installed Python 2.7.10 on my 64-bit Windows machine. When I tried to install pywinauto via `pip` command it shows some warning in green colour.

Then I tried to download (pywinauto 0.5.4) and ran the command but it shows the error: `Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pypiwin32')`.

I have also downloaded pywinauto 64-bit via https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto and ran the command `python setup.py install`.

The output is: `Error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools-scm')`

Comment: "it shows some warning in green colour." is it installed? Can you share the warning message ?

Comment: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003726B00>, 'Connection to pypi
.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pypiwin32/

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32 (from pywina
uto) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pypiwin32 (from pywinauto)

Answer (score 1):

It was some change in pypiwin32 package. Now it's restored (even better than previously because it's wheels) for Python versions before 3.6. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219 and try `pip install pywinauto` again.